# Software to draw simple state diagram with nested diagrams

Tags: diagram

I had to code certain processed which were very complex and which were undocumentated. Therefor I used yEd to capture the flow of my state machines.

En example [image]

I use these for 3 reasons.

- They are fed into a pyhton script which generates a state machine skeleton
- They act as 'automatic' software documentation
- I use them to navigate through large and complex programs and to make 
  alterations

This particular one used to be 6x bigger. Except for 3 of the states, these states merely call a nested state machine function. The nested state machine is a different state diagram.

yEd lacks the capability to handle these kind of nested state machines. It has the ability to have more than 1 open tab view, but I am looking for something betters.

What I want is this.
If I double click on a state (or use a hotkey), I want to automatically jump to the nested state diagram. I also want to be able to jump back ofcourse. I'd also like if the entire package fits in one file for more than 1 reason.

Currently I have to run a python script and feed it with one diagram. Than a compile-able ready-to-fill-in state machine is generated.

If a specific state calls a nested state machines, I could do the filling in part for that state already. Currently I cannot.

All state machines have a timer which are defined as name + T. Nested state machines make use of their 'parent's' timer. For this I have to #define the timer as the timer of the parents. If I know which is the parent state machine, I can fill in the timer definition in advance. Now I could modify the script so that the programmer is asked who the parent is. Than this problem is solved.

Now there are so many software packages out there. I don't know which one I should use.

So the summarize my whishes.

- I want a better navigation between a diagram and a sub-diagram, preferebly by clicking on states or using hotkeys
- I'd like a method to know that a state calls a nested state machine. If a state of a diagram would have a nested diagram, I could use it.
- As I feed the files into a python script, the stored files must be in ascii format or 'human readable' and not encrypted in any way.
- The software must be free of charge.

Which software package mets with these demands